# How can I adjust the CommandTImeout in DbFit for long running queries?

Tags: .net, sql-server, fitnesse, fitsharp, dbfit

Is there any way to increase the CommandTimeout for DbFit queries? I have a long running stored procedure that times out when running it in a DbFit Test.

It's possible for the procedure to run for a really long time (processing millions of records) and would like to have DbFit wait until it's completed, even if it takes several minutes.

We are using the latest version of FitSharp (downloaded it yesterday) and use the version of DbFit that is included with FitSharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the next release there will be a commandtimeout option:

|set option|command timeout|900|

http://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues#issue/52